# isloading is not changing for first time but if i change the page and come back its changing in flutter

Tags: flutter, mvvm

I am trying to call Future function which will fetch data from API from the ViewModel. But in view it is not changing my isLoading inside then function.But if I change the page and go back to the same page it is reflecting.

Comment: hey there, provide your code so others can assist you

Answer (score 0):

Make your View extends StateFulWidget and use setState function or try to use a State management library like [Provider](https://pub.dev/packages/provider).

*Provide your code if this does not solve your problem.*